# Banco de dados APP

Tags: banco-de-dados, web-service, aplicação-web, asp.net-web-api, servidor-de-aplicação

Caros amigos, em uma solução mobile tipo um aplicativo que gerencia lava jato onde usuários cria a sua conta e automaticamente já pode gerenciar seus clientes, fluxo de caixa, agendamento e etc... Esses aplicativosão consomem uma API na web, a pergunta é. Essa API possui apenas um banco de dados para gerenciar todos os usuários? ou cada usuário que registra seu lava jato tem seu banco de dados? Qual a melhor forma de criar está API?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode optar por usar Parse Server.

É uma API Open Source que permite você criar um servidor para aplicativos mobile facilmente e ainda salvar no usuário local aquilo que você desejar.

Link:
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia o parser e vi que é muito bom, mas ainda continuo com a dúvida se é um banco de dados para cada cliente ou se é apenas um banco para todos clientes da aplicação.